# Is it possible to create a procedure with a default parameter which is a metaclass?

Tags: delphi

This code:

```
type
  TMyClass = class(TObject);

procedure Foo(AClass: TClass = TMyClass);
begin
end;
```

results in:

> [dcc32 Error] E2026 Constant expression expected

Is it possible to create a procedure with a default parameter which is a metaclass?

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Parameters_(Delphi)#Default_Parameters), with my emphasis:

> You can specify default parameter values in a procedure or function heading. Default values are allowed only for typed const and value parameters. To provide a default value, end the parameter declaration with the = symbol followed by a **constant expression** that is assignment-compatible with the parameter's type.

So, what is a *constant expression*? That is covered here: [Declared Constants](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Declared_Constants). Some key excerpts:

> A constant expression is an expression that the compiler can evaluate without executing the program in which it occurs. Constant expressions include numerals; character strings; true constants; values of enumerated types; the special constants True, False, and nil; and expressions built exclusively from these elements with operators, typecasts, and set constructors.
>
> ....
>
> This definition of a constant expression is used in several places in Delphi's syntax specification. Constant expressions are required for initializing global variables, defining subrange types, assigning ordinalities to values in enumerated types, specifying default parameter values, writing case statements, and declaring both true and typed constants.
>
> ....
>
> Typed constants, unlike true constants, can hold values of array, record, procedural, and pointer types. Typed constants cannot occur in constant expressions.

So, it is not possible to declare a meta class as a constant expression. Which means that what you are trying to do is not possible.

The workaround is to use procedure overloading:

```
type
  TMyClass = class(TObject);

procedure Foo(AClass: TClass); overload;
begin
end;

procedure Foo; overload;
begin
  Foo(TMyClass);
end;
```

Comment: Thanks David. To overload then!